# ошибка при загрузке конфига python

Tags: python

написал файл config.py для программы:

```
items = {
    1: ['img/1.jpg','name','123','1']
    2: ['img/2.jpg','name1','1222','1']
    3: ['img/3.jpg','name2','31231','1']
    4: ['img/4.jpg','name3','123131232','1']
    5: ['img/5.png','name4','1231312222','1']
}
```

но при импорте появляется ошибка:

```
    2: ['img/2.jpg','name1','1222','1']
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Ну так не возможно дать ответ... предоставьте кусок кода, где импорт. Пожожда. )

Comment: ```import config```

Comment: Вы просто словарь хотите импортировать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы хотите организовать совместный доступ к глобальным переменным для нескольких модулей:
в файле config.py пишите

файл config.py для программы:

```
x = {
     1: ['img/1.jpg','name','123','1'],
     2: ['img/2.jpg','name1','1222','1'],
     3: ['img/3.jpg','name2','31231','1'],
     4: ['img/4.jpg','name3','123131232','1'],
     5: ['img/5.png','name4','1231312222','1']
    }
```

в программном модуле делаете импорт:

```
import config
print(config.x[2])# получаем значение по 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я вижу, в конце каждой строки не хватает запятой. Элементы словаря должны отделяться запятой друг от друга. Увидев вместо запятой новый ключ словаря в следующей строке питон и даёт ошибку. То есть должно быть так:

```
items = {
    1: ['img/1.jpg','name','123','1'],
    2: ['img/2.jpg','name1','1222','1'],
    3: ['img/3.jpg','name2','31231','1'],
    4: ['img/4.jpg','name3','123131232','1'],
    5: ['img/5.png','name4','1231312222','1']
}
```

Comment: Согласен, пропустил, исправлюсь... )